# Writing the Dispatcher.Invoke VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dispatcher

Im just trying to figure out the syntax for a Dispatcher.Invoke in vb.net. I have it working in a C# application, but now i need the VB form. Here is the code i have for my C# application

```
 this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            SOME CODE
        }));
```

All online sources seem to be C#, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can probably just Google for *Lambda expressions VB.NET* and get something [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)

Comment: those guys in that link sure do know a lot about .NET

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()

   ' CODE 

  End Sub)
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something easy, just couldn't find the syntax.

Comment: That's awesome! The Telerik converter puts Function() instead of Sub(), which doesn't work if there aren't any parameters.